# Cannot install MySQL-python package

Tags: mysql, centos7, mysql-python

I have CentOS 7 just created in hosting company.

I need to install an application that depends on MySQL-python package.

I tried to install that package, but it is not available:

```
root@vps [/var/frappe]# yum install MySQL-python
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, universal-hooks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * EA4: 208.100.0.204
 * base: ftpmirror.your.org
 * epel: mirror.steadfastnet.com
 * extras: ftpmirror.your.org
 * ius: muug.ca
 * updates: ftpmirror.your.org
No package MySQL-python available.
Error: Nothing to do
root@vps [/var/frappe]#
```

Why I cannot install it? some workaround?

EDIT:

/etc/yum.conf

```
[main]
exclude=courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* p0f php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* spamassassin* squirrelmail*
tolerant=1
errorlevel=1
cachedir=/var/cache/yum/$basearch/$releasever
keepcache=0
debuglevel=2
logfile=/var/log/yum.log
exactarch=1
obsoletes=1
gpgcheck=1
plugins=1
installonly_limit=5
bugtracker_url=http://bugs.centos.org/set_project.php?project_id=23&ref=http://bugs.centos.org/bug_report_page.php?category=yum
distroverpkg=centos-release


#  This is the default, if you make this bigger yum won't see if the metadata
# is newer on the remote and so you'll "gain" the bandwidth of not having to
# download the new metadata and "pay" for it by yum not having correct
# information.
#  It is esp. important, to have correct metadata, for distributions like
# Fedora which don't keep old packages around. If you don't like this checking
# interupting your command line usage, it's much better to have something
# manually check the metadata once an hour (yum-updatesd will do this).
# metadata_expire=90m

# PUT YOUR REPOS HERE OR IN separate files named file.repo
# in /etc/yum.repos.d
```

Comment: Try a `yum update`. Check the mirrors are actually being updated. Even `docker run centos:7 yum search  MySQL-python` finds it for me. So hosting/default repos problem.

Comment: it did not work either... what is docker.....?

Comment: What is 'it' - 'yum update' or 'checking the mirrors' ? Rather than a meaningless statement like "did not work" show the actual results/observations and if needed the expected results? docker is a way to run fairly pristine operating systems in this case for demonstration purposes.

Comment: I have run "yum update"...I don't know how to check the mirrors. It is supposed all repositories are well configured.

Comment: Given it fails to install the package I suspect it isn't properly configured. Compare the urls that you have obscured in your question against the directory of a public centos like http://mirror.centos.org/centos-7/7/ or set your mirror [like this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/365106/centos-yum-specify-mirror) and try again. Or contact your hosting provider for the support that comes with their broken service.

Comment: Can you show us your `/etc/yum.conf `

Comment: @DanFromGermany added in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

this package would be available in the `base` repository:

```
$ yum whatprovides MySQL-python
MySQL-python-1.2.5-1.el7.x86_64 : An interface to MySQL
Repo        : base
```

for reference:

```
$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/centos.repo 
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
protect=1
priority=5
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

what looks quite suspicious in the provided `yum.conf` is that config `exclude=mysql*` precisely matches the desired package name. you'd either have to remove that one `exclude` pattern to install. or install package [MySQL-python](https://pypi.org/project/MySQL-python/) with `pip install MySQL-python`.

---

the `RPM` dependencies of `MySQL-python` confirm that no additional `MySQL` packages are required:

```
$ repoquery --requires --resolve MySQL-python
python-0:2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
python-libs-0:2.7.5-76.el7.x86_64
MariaDB-compat-0:10.2.22-1.el7.centos.x86_64
glibc-0:2.17-260.el7.i686
mariadb-libs-1:5.5.60-1.el7_5.x86_64
zlib-0:1.2.7-18.el7.x86_64
glibc-0:2.17-260.el7.x86_64
openssl-libs-1:1.0.2k-16.el7.x86_64
```

---

the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/yum.conf.5.html) also explains, what I'm trying to tell:

> **exclude** List of packages to exclude from all repositories, so `yum` works as if that package was never in the repositories. This should be a space separated list. This is commonly used so a package isn't upgraded or installed accidentally, but can be used to remove packages in any way that `yum list` will show packages. Shell globs using wildcards (eg. `*` and `?`) are allowed.

the optimal solution would be: to edit `/etc/yum.conf` and then replace `exclude` pattern `mysql*` with something alike `mysql-server* mysql-client* mysql-libs*` - so that `MySQL` server, client and libs would still be excluded, but the installation of package `MySQL-python` would be permitted.

---

there is even a quite simple way around the issue (be aware, that this will not find updates later on):

```
sudo yum install MySQL-python --disableexcludes=all
```

Comment: "yum whatprovides MySQL-python" shows the message "No matches found"

Comment: And I have installed it using pip, however, the software that depends on it, does not recognize it as installed.

Comment: @jstuardo then you have to install it with `yum` (by removing the exclusion, which might nevertheless exist for some reason, which might be MariaDB) - the `pip` installation would require disabling the dependency-check. MariaDB at least provides (most) mySQL compatibility libraries, so that using either of them is less of a problem. the actual problem is, that the `exclude` pattern also matches the desired package name, despite it's not part of mySQL server. added the list of dependencies.

Comment: @jstuardo unless you remove the `exclude` pattern `mysql*` from `/etc/yum.conf`... it will not find the package, because this also matches `MySQL-python`. this appears to be a side effect of trying to exclude the `MySQL` server; they should have used a pattern alike `mysql-server* mysql-client* mysql-libs*` instead, so that it would not match `MySQL-python` (you could notify them of the issue, which they've unknowingly produced).

Comment: thanks!! I could install that package by following your suggestion

Comment: @jstuardo no problem (while knowing `RPM` in detail). looking forward to the bounty :)

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using `pip` as the package manager for Python, instead of `yum`. [Create a Python virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html), activate it, then use `pip` to install `MySQL-python`:

```
python -m venv ~/mysqlstuff
source ~/mysqlstuff/bin/activate
pip install MySQL-python
```

Answer (score 0):

First update your package manager with:

```
sudo yum update
```

Then install pip package with:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
sudo yum install python-pip
```

Then update pip with:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Finally install the MYSQL-python package:

```
pip install --user MySQL-python # user only
```

or

```
sudo pip install MySQL-python # system wide
```